# Generating more than one output file from a template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-generation, t4

Hi 
I am writing a custom template generator for my xml file. I was wondering if you guys can tell me a way I can generate more than one output file from the template under the same template.

The no of file should depend on the no of xml files I input

If I want to generate the c# class for a.xml I am doing something like this

```
<#= XmlToCsGenerator.Xml(this.Host.ResolvePath("a.xml")) #>
```

where my  function XmlToCsGenerator.Xml(string path) returns the string to be written into the file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damien Guard's approach detailed here:
http://damieng.com/blog/2009/11/06/multiple-outputs-from-t4-made-easy-revisited
is a good one too.  This is very close to the approach used in the Entity Framework's use of T4 in the .Net 4.0 product.

Comment: Please consider including the gist of the proposed approach here as well.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this article/sample:

http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-creating-complex-code-generators/

Author has illustrated creating multiple delete procedures (corresponding to multiple tables) for single template.